# Logic written in Platform Event Trigger doesn't work, but the same logic works from ProcessBuilder

Tags: apex, process-builder, webservices, platform-event, apex-webservice

I am using `Platform Events`, to fire a webservice(HTTP request) call post transaction commit, let us say Once Account is Created or Account Updated. In the process of doing so, I am able to create/publish Platform Events from the (Account/any Object) Triggers.

**Trigger as PlatformEvent Subscriber:**

As a Platform Event subscriber, I have written a Trigger on PlatformEvent. Logic written inside the trigger is not completely working, in other words partially working. In detail, in the logic I have added Debug statements as a first line and my further logic is to query a record and send those details in a webservice(HTTP) and update a record based on the `HTTPResponse` received.

In this scenario, debug statement is getting executed but neither query nor webservice call happening. I assume this is because of '`Automated Process`' user do not have enough permissions on Object (to query) or Apex class( to invoke)from Trigger. I believe, we do not have any control on this user or it's profile. Correct me if I am wrong?

**Work around I have used:** The same logic is written in an Invocable method and used ProcessBuilder as PlatformEvent sbscriber. This is working perfectly.

**Query:** Is it a known issue that we cannot use Triggers as PlatformEvent subscriber? If not, do we have any approach to change Automated Process user's profile permissions? Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mind posting some of your PlatformEvent trigger code?  Do you have a `try catch` setup in the trigger?

Comment: are you doing a callout from future? because you cannot do callout directly in platform event trigger:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/263092/19118

Comment: If you have to do callout from Platform Event then probably you should not use |Events at all. Use normal Queuable, future.

Comment: Triggers CAN be PE subscribers; I use them all the time; Context user for PE subscribers is `Automated Process` user and such user has access to all objects (with some exceptions such as when used in VF Email component controllers)